# In AI/ML, using the Perceptron model, would it ever make sense to have both negative weights and data?

Tags: machine-learning, perceptron

I understand the math but I want to make sure I understand the mapping back to real world scenarios. Thinking about it logically, I cannot think of a real world scenario where you would have a scenario where you would want both the weight of the data and the data itself to potentially be negative. Is there such a scenario I'm not thinking of?

Ex: $y = sign(b + \sum_{i=1}^{d} w_ix_i)$ where both $w_i$ and $x_i$ could be negative?

My reasoning is that I cannot think of a real world mapping where a double negative resulting in a positive makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Example: $x$ is temperature , $y$ is 1 if cold, -1 otherwise.
$$
y = \texttt{sign}(-1 \cdot -3) = 1.
$$